# Techniques for "fairer" dice rolls?

Tags: random

Suppose I have a game with 6 players, each of which gets a payout on a different side of a D6 roll. The D6 is rolled many times over the course of the game.

This yields an even payout in the long run, using an unbiased D6. However, my game is not long enough for the payouts to revert to the mean. Therefore, I want to make a *biased* dice mechanism, where rolls that have not come up recently are more likely.

One approach I can think of is to simulate a deck of cards:

1. Take a list `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]`
2. Repeat the list `n` times (where `n` is some multiple of the typical game length)
3. Shuffle the list
4. To make a "roll", pop a number off of the list

The problem with this approach is choosing `n`... too low and we risk running out of rolls; too high and the rolls are not biased enough.

**What algorithms / techniques are available here?**

It is also beneficial if the algorithm can be easily explained to the player.

Comment: What about refilling the list once it's empty?

Comment: That would create a weird effect where the rolls get less and less random and then suddenly more random again. Players would also be able to count rolls to know when this happens.

Comment: [You may be interested in this recent Q&A, asking for a middle-ground between raw unbiased randomness and shuffle bags](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/201805/39518)

Comment: Rolling 2 die and summing the result reduces the chances of rolling extreme values significantly. Perhaps that might be an easy way to make the rolls a bit more predictable. For example a result of 7 is much more likely than 2 or 12.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of [Looking for a middle ground between raw random and shuffle bags](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/201805/looking-for-a-middle-ground-between-raw-random-and-shuffle-bags)